# How to allow a specific folder and his files by .htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i got the follow .htacess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

how can i allow the follow directory and his files by the .htaccess:

/var/www/html/orangejuice/www/wp-content/themes/dreamtheme/iframes

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. A simple one is to add the directory in question to the first RewriteRule to exclude it:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$|themes/dreamtheme/iframes/.* - [L]
```

Test it in a fresh browser in incognito mode.